# How to fix this error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have high number of functions which are binding to different elements.

Hence, I decided to define all my functions in one file & then call from other file.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/functions.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    Hello!! This is a sample page
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
//like this I have 50+ functions 
function GetCustomers()
{

   //ajax call.
}

});
```

site.js

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
 GetCustomers();
});
```

But this is throwing the below error.

[image: Error]

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GetCustomers is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the function inside document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

 function GetCustomers()
{

 //ajax call.
 }

});
```

Use like

```
<script>

function GetCustomers()
{

 //ajax call.
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any way better to do the same??

Comment: you can use outside . function GetCustomers(){ //ajax call. }

Comment: It is rendering..Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
//like this I have 50+ functions 
function GetCustomers()
{

   //ajax call.
}

});
```

You define the function inside the ready handler, keeping it local to that scope. Move it outside (or just get rid of the `$(document).ready()`) so that's it's in global scope. See function scoping docs.

If you don't want to add all of these functions to the global scope, you could create an global object, and add these as methods:

```
var app = {
    getCustomers: function(){},
    ...
};
```

Comment: Userful Link added. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any better way to do the same. As this will poulte the window global namespace

Answer (score 2):

Remove the wrapping $(document).ready() from your functions.js

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wrap all your functions in `$(document).ready` and that's your issue. Two-problems:

1. `.ready` doesn't fire away so that code isn't executed (and
   therefore your functions aren't created)
2. since you're doing it in .ready your not binding your functions to the window and so they can't be accessed anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

write your function out side the document.ready()

```
 <script>
   function GetCustomers()
   {
       //your code.
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull your `GetCustomers` out of the document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

don't use GetCustomers inside document.ready in functions.js intead of directly define function if you are defining in separate file.